# Intellij compiles and builds all classes (does not seem to use cache)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, compilation

I have the following problem with my IntelliJ (v12 or v13 Ultimate). Whenever I make my project (Ctrl+F9) or build some artifacts, it starts building everything from scratch. Normally it uses some caches and only compiles the classes that have changed, but not today. This is making me waste a lot of time, because a full project build takes a couple of minutes. I have invalidated my caches, uninstalled IntelliJ completely from my computer but to no effect.

Theoretically, my project configuration is identical to that of my colleagues, because we use an internal tool for configuring our projects, so I'm more inclined to think that it might have something to do with my machine settings.

Note: I noticed this behavior some time after deleting some registry keys that pointed to an old java installation. I doubt this could have anything to do with this issue, but thought I'd add it here just in case.

Any help would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working after a machine reboot. It seems that on Windows, when nothing else works, just do a reboot.